# app reverts all input variables to defaults after some time

Tags: swift

I wrote my fist app, very simple, that creates a user defined number of badges at random times during a user defined window of time. It works fine but after some time (not sure how long, 2-4 hours), all of the user input information reverts to the defaults of the program. The issue is it is supposed to run each day but it is annoying to have to set it each morning. I am not sure if this is a coding issue or if the app 'reboots' when it is not doing anything in the background. Note that this occurs on my iPhone 8 but not on the simulator (or I am not patient enough for it to occur on the simulator).

I have put several print and label to try to identify when it occurs; I am sure I am putting them in the correct places. I apologize for including so much code - I tried to weed some of the mistakes out but I do not know where the problem is.

```
import UserNotifications
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var EarlyTimePicker: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var LateTimePicker: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var NumQuestions: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel_Questions: UILabel!// Attached to the label box

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel_StartEndTime: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel_TestResetTime: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel_CurrentEarlyTime: UILabel!

private var earlyTimePicker: UIDatePicker?
private var lateTimePicker: UIDatePicker?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in //ask for permission in order to show messages on the lock screen
        if granted {
            print("Yay!")
        } else {
            print("D'oh")
        }
    }


    earlyTimePicker = UIDatePicker()
    earlyTimePicker?.datePickerMode = .time //change to .time
    earlyTimePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.earlyTimeChanged(earlyTimePicker:)),for: .valueChanged)

    lateTimePicker = UIDatePicker()
    lateTimePicker?.datePickerMode = .time //change to .time
    lateTimePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.lateTimeChanged(lateTimePicker:)),for: .valueChanged)

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    EarlyTimePicker.inputView = earlyTimePicker
    LateTimePicker.inputView = lateTimePicker


    }

@objc func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    view.endEditing(true)

}


var earlyTime=480
var earlyTimehour=0
var earlyTimeminute=0


@objc func earlyTimeChanged(earlyTimePicker: UIDatePicker){

    let earlyTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    earlyTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    earlyTimeFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    earlyTimeFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    EarlyTimePicker.text = earlyTimeFormatter.string(from: earlyTimePicker.date)
    view.endEditing(true)

    let earlyTimedate = earlyTimePicker.date
    let earlyTimecomponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: earlyTimedate)
    earlyTimehour = earlyTimecomponents.hour!
    earlyTimeminute = earlyTimecomponents.minute!
    earlyTime = earlyTimecomponents.hour! * 60 + earlyTimecomponents.minute!


    print("earlyTimehour: \(earlyTimecomponents.hour!)")
    print("earlyTimeminute: \(earlyTimecomponents)")
    print("earlyTime: \(earlyTime)")
    print("Current Time: \(Date())")


}

var lateTime=1200
var lateTimehour=0
var lateTimeminute=0

@objc func lateTimeChanged(lateTimePicker: UIDatePicker){
    let lateTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    lateTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    lateTimeFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    lateTimeFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    LateTimePicker.text = lateTimeFormatter.string(from: lateTimePicker.date)
    view.endEditing(true)

    let lateTimedate = lateTimePicker.date
    let lateTimecomponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: lateTimedate)
    lateTimehour = lateTimecomponents.hour!
    lateTimeminute = lateTimecomponents.minute!
    lateTime = lateTimecomponents.hour! * 60 + lateTimecomponents.minute!

    let testMinute = lateTime % 60
    let testHour = lateTime / 60

    print("lateTimehour: \(lateTimecomponents.hour!)")
    print("lateTimeminute: \(lateTimecomponents)")
    print("lateTime: \(lateTime)")
    print("testHour: \(testHour)")
    print("testMinute: \(testMinute)")

    myLabel_TestResetTime.text = "Time Set \(Date())"
    myLabel_CurrentEarlyTime.text = "Current Early Time: \(earlyTime) / OnOff: \(OnOff)"

}


let PickedString = ["One","Two","Three","Four", "Five","Six","Seven","Eight"]



// @IBAction func TestCallFunction(_ sender: UIButton) {
// scheduleLocal()
// }

//NEED TO REPEAT THIS FUNCTION AT EARLY TIME - 10
//need to stop repeating with a cancel button (while bool true, do it, while false, stop. Default is false)

    var RunDaily: Timer?

var OnOff = false
var QuestionNum = 1


@IBAction func Launch(_ sender: UIButton) {
    OnOff = true
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()


    guard let QuestionNumA = Int(NumQuestions.text!) else { //This is how to get the UserInterface VALUE as a number
        print("not a number!: \(String(describing: NumQuestions.text))")
        return
    }
    print("Number of Questions: \(QuestionNumA)")

  //      var QuestionNum = 1
    if QuestionNumA > 10 {QuestionNum=10} else {QuestionNum=QuestionNumA}
    print("QuestionNumA:\(QuestionNumA) vs QuestionNum: \(QuestionNum)")

    printStuff()
    showMessage()
}
@IBAction func Stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
    OnOff = false
    printStuff()
}

func printStuff() {
    if OnOff == true {
        print("Bool is On : \(OnOff)")
        RunDaily = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 86400, target: self, selector: #selector(showMessage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)//86400


    }

    if OnOff == false {
        print("Bool is Off : \(OnOff)")
        RunDaily?.invalidate()
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    }
}

     func SaveDefaultData(){ // THis is the structure to SAVE input data for when the app relaunches (causes error when run.
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set("Date()", forKey:"key1")
    //defaults.set(earlyTimePicker, forKey:"earlyTimePickerSet") cannot set earlyTimePicker. causes crash
   // defaults.set(lateTimePicker, forKey:"lateTimePickerSet")
    defaults.set(earlyTime, forKey:"earlyTimeSet")
    defaults.set(lateTime, forKey:"lateTimeSet")
    defaults.set(QuestionNum, forKey:"QuestionNumSet")

}

func SetDefaultData(){// THis is the structure to Set input for when the app relaunches
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let savedValue = defaults.string(forKey: "key1"){
            print("Here you will get saved value \(savedValue)")
        } else {
            print("No value in Userdefault,Either you can save value here or perform other operation")
            defaults.set("Here you can save value", forKey: "key1")
        }

    if let earlyTimeValue = defaults.string(forKey: "earlyTimeSet"){
        print("Here you will get saved value \(earlyTimeValue)")
        earlyTime = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "earlyTimeSet") as? Int ?? 485
    } else {
        print("No value in Userdefault,Either you can save value here or perform other operation")
        defaults.set("Here you can save value", forKey: "earlyTimeSet")
        earlyTime = 500
    }

    if let lateTimeValue = defaults.string(forKey: "lateTimeSet"){
        print("Here you will get saved value \(lateTimeValue)")
        lateTime = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lateTimeSet") as? Int ?? 1265
    } else {
        print("No value in Userdefault,Either you can save value here or perform other operation")
        defaults.set("Here you can save value", forKey: "lateTimeSet")
        lateTime = 1230
    }

    if let QuestionNumValue = defaults.string(forKey: "QuestionNumSet"){
        print("Here you will get saved value \(QuestionNumValue)")
        QuestionNum = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "QuestionNumSet") as? Int ?? 4
    } else {
        print("No value in Userdefault,Either you can save value here or perform other operation")
        defaults.set("Here you can save value", forKey: "QuestionNumSet")
        QuestionNum = 2
    }
}



@objc func showMessage() {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    if lateTime <= earlyTime {
        lateTime = earlyTime+1
        if earlyTimehour <= 12 {
            LateTimePicker.text = "\(earlyTimehour):\(earlyTimeminute) AM"
        }
        if earlyTimehour > 12 {
            let EarlyTimeAfternoon = earlyTimehour - 12
            LateTimePicker.text = "\(EarlyTimeAfternoon):\(earlyTimeminute) PM"
        }
    }

   // center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    // THIS IS WHERE ALL THE USER INPUT GETS INTO THE PROGRAM //
  //  guard let QuestionNumA = Int(NumQuestions.text!) else { //This is how to get the UserInterface VALUE as a number
 //          print("not a number!: \(String(describing: NumQuestions.text))")
  //        return
    //  }
    //print("Number of Questions: \(QuestionNumA)")


    // THIS IS WHERE ALL THE USER INPUT GETS INTO THE PROGRAM //

    var RandHourArray:[Int] = [0]
    var RandMinArray:[Int] = [0]
    var RandQuestionArray:[Int] = [0]
    var Counter = 1
   // var QuestionNum = 1
    //if QuestionNumA > 2 {QuestionNum=10} else {QuestionNum=QuestionNumA}
 //   print("QuestionNumA:\(QuestionNumA) vs QuestionNum: \(QuestionNum)")

    for _ in 0 ... QuestionNum-1{

        // Pick random times for badges

        //let RandHour = Int.random(in: earlyTimehour ... lateTimehour)
        let RandTimeMinFromMidnight = Int.random(in: self.earlyTime ... self.lateTime)
        let ConvertRandTimeHours = RandTimeMinFromMidnight / 60
        let ConvertRandTimeMinutes = RandTimeMinFromMidnight % 60
        RandHourArray.append(ConvertRandTimeHours)
        //let RandMin = Int.random(in: earlyTimeminute ... lateTimeminute)
        RandMinArray.append(ConvertRandTimeMinutes)
        let RandQuestion = Int.random(in: 0 ... self.PickedString.count-1)
        RandQuestionArray.append(RandQuestion)

        //print("RandTimeMinFromMidnight: \(RandTimeMinFromMidnight)")
  //        print("RandHourArray: \(RandHourArray)")
  //      print("ConvertRandTimeHours: \(ConvertRandTimeHours)")
    //    print("RandMinArray: \(RandMinArray)")
      //  print("ConvertRandTimeMinutes: \(ConvertRandTimeMinutes)")

    }

    myLabel_Questions.text = "# of questions: \(QuestionNum)"//\(QuestionNumA)"
    myLabel_StartEndTime.text = "Start Time \(earlyTime) / End Time \(lateTime)"


    let content_A = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content_A.title = "Prompt"
    content_A.body = self.PickedString[RandQuestionArray[Counter]] // 
    content_A.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content_A.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content_A.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    var dateComponents_A = DateComponents()
    dateComponents_A.hour = RandHourArray[Counter]
    dateComponents_A.minute = RandMinArray[Counter]
       let trigger_A = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents_A, repeats: false)

    let request_A = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content_A, trigger: trigger_A)
    center.add(request_A)
    print("Request A time: \(RandHourArray[Counter]) : \(RandMinArray[Counter])")
    print("Question String picked A: \(self.PickedString[RandQuestionArray[Counter]])")

    Counter=2
    if Counter<=QuestionNum {
        let content_B = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content_B.title = "Prompt"
             content_B.body = self.PickedString[RandQuestionArray[Counter]]
        content_B.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
        content_B.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
        content_B.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        var dateComponents_B = DateComponents()
         dateComponents_B.hour = RandHourArray[Counter]
        dateComponents_B.minute = RandMinArray[Counter]
         let trigger_B = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents_B, repeats: false)

        let request_B = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content_B, trigger: trigger_B)
        center.add(request_B)
        print("Request B time: \(RandHourArray[Counter]) : \(RandMinArray[Counter])")
        print("Question String picked B: \(self.PickedString[RandQuestionArray[Counter]])")
    }

}
}
```

Comment: does this occur every time you close application?, i cant find any code for storing data in your code...

Comment: You should store your data inside UserDefaults, Keychain and Core Data or other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your data inside UserDefaults, Keychain and Core Data or other stuff. if you dont store your data every time you close the application all the data will deallocate from the memory because they were stored in the heap.

Unsaved data:

```
let myLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
myLabel.text = "Some text"
```

Should save like:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(myLabel.text, forKey: "it.is.custom")
```

And load like:

```
myLabel.text = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "it.is.custom") as? String
```

refrence to study: https://fluffy.es/persist-data/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into how to code this (I am pretty new to this language) and let you know. I really appreciate you taking the time

Comment: YES, never a moment of frustration!!! If it is easy for you (I expect it is), would you drop a line of code for how one would store the info for  @IBOutlet weak var NumQuestions: UITextField!  (or associated QuestionNumA) as an example. Also where it goes (in or outside of a function). Thanks a lot

Comment: I know I am dense, I apologize. 2 questions. First, I do not see how to use this with a UITextField (ie the NumQuestions: UITextField!). Second, I am not sure where in the code to put these (within func viewDidLoad() or elsewhere). I think I got this first one the rest would come easy - but everything I try gives Compiler errors.

Comment: Thank you a ton mohamad reza koohkan. I figured out how to make it run correctly (I think) using the SaveDefaultData and SetDefaultData functions now in the code. I do not know how to read those back to the UITextFields, but at least the app seems to be working correctly

Comment: good job... so if you found my answer helpful please let is as answer.